# Rabbi Sheinberg Hebrew Shiurim online

Tags: product-recommendation

I hope this is an appropriate question for this forum.

I seek shiurim, of any kind, in Hebrew by Rabbi Chaim Pinchas Sheinberg Zt”l that are available on the internet.

Thank you for any afforts.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Gevalt. Great to have you join, hope you will stay and learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

The first speaker [HERE](http://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Media/PlayShiur.aspx?FileName=1011-20141113-132855-%D7%A2%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A6%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A1_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%92_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%A1_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F.mp3&ShiurNum=59) is Rabbi Chaim Pinchas Sheinberg Zt”l.